# how to apply floating label to edit text in android in java file instead of xml

Tags: android, material-design

I want to know is there any way we can apply floating label for edit text using java instead of xml. If yes please tell me the way how to do the same.

Comment: Go through the source code and copy the relevant parts and modify the same to make it work for oyu

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/11247418. Modify according to your needs. Its a LinerLayout ie a VIewGroup you can ass childs views  to ir programatically

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do in xml you can do programmatically {it MUST be so, otherwise `inflate` would not work ;O)} (here's some bare-bones):

```
    public class EditActivity extends Activity
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        m_context = getApplicationContext();

        m_context.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);//VERY IMPORTANT this must inherit Theme.AppCompat
        LinearLayout      ll_Main    = new LinearLayout(m_context);
        TextInputLayout   textLayout = new TextInputLayout(m_context);
        AppCompatEditText editText   = new AppCompatEditText(m_context);
//      EditText          editText   = new EditText(m_context);//this works also
        editText.setText("text");
        editText.setHint("hint");
        textLayout.addView(editText);

        ll_Main.addView(textLayout);
        setContentView(ll_Main);
        }
    }
```